# How to access a value from node backend in js frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to access a value from my node backend in a js file.

Heres the node code... 
Node:

```js
(async () => {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [{
            name: 'T-shirt',
            description: 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
            images: ['https://example.com/t-shirt.png'],
            amount: 500,
            currency: 'eur',
            quantity: ((req.body.tickets - 0) + (req.body.tickets_kid - 0)),
        }],
        success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/thank-you?session_id={session.id}',
        cancel_url: 'https://localhost:3000/tickets',
});

res.send(session);
})();
```

...and the js code

```
const stripe = Stripe('secretkey');

const session = ?
console.log(session);

async function stripeCheckout() {
    console.log('activated checkout')

    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
        // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
        // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
        sessionId: '{{session.id}}'
    })
    window.alert(error.message);
    // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
    // error, display the localized error message to your customer
    // using `error.message`.
};
```

Now Im trying to get the session id into the js file.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some request to the backend to get the response of that.

Let's suppose that in the backend is an Express "controller" mapped on `/stripe-session` end point on GET http method.

You can  fetch the response of `/stripe-session` using `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API or some library like axios https://github.com/axios/axios

```
const response = await fetch(`/stripe-session`);
const session = await response.json()
```

Comment: ok so it is not possible to go from the order page (the page on which the button that triggers the function in the js file is located) to the checkout page directly?

Comment: I will depend on how the session is created. I supposed the session object created was a Javascript object and the `res.send(session)` method sends that object from the request. 

Once you have that session object in your frontend js code, you can get the id property if exists on it, just doing `{ sessionId: session.id }`

Comment: ok because for me the res.send just redirects to the destination URL specified in the form and does not respond with the proper actions (as declared in the function).

Comment: <form name="Tickets_form" id="Form" action="/tickets/checkout" method="POST">
                <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="stripeCheckout();">Order tickets</button> <br>
            </form>

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending response back to client. You can easily access that response where ever you want. For example:

```
 url: `${appUrl}/open_api/chatbot/getProjectDetails?projectId=${project}&appId=${appId}`,
     }).then(function (projectDetails) {
       if (projectDetails) {
         var botChatValue = projectDetails.data.result.response
```

In above there is api getting called and response coming back to projectDetails. Now you can easily access it. 
You can explain bit more if your query is different.